# WebSphere 8.5 Application Installation Directory

Tags: installation, websphere

Where in the Admin Console can I find an application's installation directory?  I have installed applications but I have no clue where they were installed to.

Answer (score 0):

I found it after some hunting.  I went to "Applications", "Application Types", "WebSphere enterprise applications".  Then clicked on the application.  Then clicked on "Application Binaries" and it was right there.

Then I took the variables and find the values in "Environment", "WebSphere variables"